# My Button Keeps On Disappearing After Clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I made a game of rock, paper, scissors and the button that I have at the end of my code, and after you click on it once, it disappears, and it would make no sense to keep on repeating that code again and again.

```js
function game(){ 
    var userChoice= prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");
    document.write("You chose " + userChoice + ". <br/>")
    var computerChoice= Math.random();
    if(computerChoice<=0.33){
        computerChoice="rock";
    }
    else if(computerChoice<=0.67){
        computerChoice="paper";
    }
    else{
        computerChoice="scissors";
    }
    document.write("The computer chose " + computerChoice + ". <br/>");
    if(userChoice==computerChoice){
        document.write("TIE!!!!");
    }
    else if(userChoice=="paper" && computerChoice=="rock"){
        document.write('<span style="color:red">You win!</span>');
    }
    else if(userChoice=="rock" && computerChoice=="scissors"){
        document.write('<span style="color:red">You win!</span>');
    }
    else if(userChoice=="scissors" && computerChoice=="paper"){
        document.write('<span style="color:red">You win!</span>');
    }
    else if(userChoice=="scissors" && computerChoice=="rock"){
        document.write('Sorry, you lose.');
    }
    else if(userChoice=="rock" && computerChoice=="paper"){
        document.write("Sorry, you lose.");
    }
    else if(userChoice=="paper" && computerChoice=="scissors"){
        document.write("Sorry, you lose.");
    }
    else if(userChoice=="Chuck Norris"){
        document.write("This program bows down to your superiority, YOU WIN!!!!");
    }
    document.write('<button type="button" style="display:block;"  onclick="game()">Play Again!</button>');

}
```

```html
<body onload="game()">
```

Comment: seems fine to me http://plnkr.co/edit/MglqlZDjTOM5wLMHx8It?p=preview

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`. Use DOM to manipulate UI.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XFwdk/1/

Comment: @bagava2 Check out this demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/xBubp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the code to an element like the following or something like that.  Document.write tends make stuff disappear.

```
<h1 id='myText'></h1>
```

document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'what I was writing to the document'

Answer (score 2):

Forget about document.write. Use a div to write the content to.

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

And write to the div like this:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "Sorry, you lose";
```

Of course you can put "mydiv" into a variable and reuse it.

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
mydiv.innerHTML += "Sorry, you lose";
mydiv.innerHTML += "Sorry again";
```